# Azure Server 2008 R2 virtual machine Issue - .Net CAS Policy Manager Buffer Overflow

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, cas

I and others get error "Microsoft .NET Framework CAS Policy Manager has stopped working" when attempting to install Visual Studio or SQL Server Express (or standard) on a Azure Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine.  The error occurs installing any version of SQL Server Express (2008,2012, 2014), or when trying to install Visual Studio Express 2008.

Can someone explain why I get the error, or better yet one simple set of things to do to eliminate the error and install at least one version of SQL Server Express (2008, 2012, 2014)?

**Do this to duplicate the problem:** Create a new Azure server 2008 R2 virtual machine (Basic, A2 or Standard, A2).  On startup (no other setup, roles or features added) try to install SQL Server Manager express 2012 with tools (x64).  Get the error!
Here are the error details:

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BEX64
  Application Name: caspol.exe
  Application Version: 2.0.50727.5483
  Application Timestamp: 530eed35
  Fault Module Name: System.Data.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.0.50727.5483
  Fault Module Timestamp: 530eeed9
  Exception Offset: 00000000001d169d
  Exception Code: c0000409
  Exception Data: 0000000000000000
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.400.8
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: bf02
  Additional Information 2: bf027ecb1f69aa98c58b61a0f9389270
  Additional Information 3: 9768
  Additional Information 4: 97683641a469f4f5a75bd7b4e8af76de

By the way, it does not have to be a newly created machine, the same error occurs after adding .Net 3.5.1 (and or 4.5.2) Framework, Adding IIS, Adding Visual studio Community....  I tried 10 or so combindations over a week to try to get SQL Server Express to install with no luck.

**Here is perhaps a related symptom:**  Using Cmd window:
Navigate to folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\
Enter command  caspol.exe -machine -reset
This will cause an error "Microsoft .NET Framework CAS Policy Manager has stopped working". Debug with Visual Studio shows an unhandled win32 exception occurred in caspol.exe[2960] First window in debugger: A buffer overrun has occurred in CasPol.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state. Note that if I run that command on any of the 3 other copies of caspol.exe (..Framework\v4.xxx or ..Framework64\ver4.xxx or Framework\V2.xxxx) the command succeeds. I delete and recreate a new virtual machine after this command since I have no idea if it creates other problems.

Thanks for any suggestions or help

d

Comment: I found the answer (thanks to a Twitter user):  Prior to installing SQL Server (any version, 2008,20012,2014..., express, standard Etc.) or any product that installs a version of SQL Server on an Azure Windows Server 2008 R2 (SP1):  **After creating the VM, Install ALL OS updates, including ALL optional updates. Continue restarting the OS until no further updates are found.**

Answer (score 1):

Same situation here i.e. Azure Server 2008 R2 VM.  Note that the error's details specify 'Fault Module' as 'System.Data.dll'.  Find and delete the appropriate native image generated from the assembly 'System.Data.dll', i.e. C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Data\326df77841f23d0e0039374a7d233416\System.Data.**ni**.dll.  It appears something corrupts it in this particular VM image, not matter what you do.  Once I deleted 'System.Data.ni.dll', it worked.

Reference:
http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/mersh/archive/2015/05/27/landing-page-vanishes-after-you-try-to-set-up-a-new-instance-of-sql-or-add-a-new-feature-to-the-existing-installation-of-sql.aspx

Comment: THAT was it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After creating the VM, Install ALL OS updates, including ALL optional updates. Continue restarting the OS until no further updates are found.